# Select tag in html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, knockout.js

I want send `<form>` from client, and one of fields in the `<form>` is `<select>`.
I am using knockout data binding.

```
<form method="get" action="http://google.com/" target="_blank">
    <input data-bind="text: name" name="meow">
    <select name="dog" data-bind="options: objects, 
                                  optionsText: function(item){return item.secid},
                                  optionsValue : $data.id">
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

But value from select is always empty in request. Any ideas?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Y4G/) is here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `$data.id` with `function(item){return item.id}`

Comment: @Ilya Actually it will also work with only the property names: `optionsText: 'secid', optionsValue : 'id'` Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/eqMMV/